# show value from stdClass Object jquery

Tags: jquery

Hy everyone 
I have a ajax consult.

```
        var datos;



        function devuelve(link, callback){
            $.ajax({
                url: link,

                success: function(data){
                    datos = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    callback(datos);
                    alert(datos);
                }
            });
        }

        devuelve (eldata.link, function(response){
            //alert(datos);
        });
```

This ajax ejecute a function that return a view the view have this

```
<?php
   echo json_encode($this->items);
?>
```

now I want to manipulate the value of the data to show  this

```
this.$description.html(datos.name);
```

but dont work, any idea

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a `stdClass Object`.  It seems like you need to edit the server-side code and have it `json_encode` your object.  What *exactly* are you being returned?  What does `console.log(datos)` show?  And why do you have `async: false`?

Comment: Hi @RocketHazmat I explain better I have a method that return this view    echo json_encode($this->items); this value I want to manipulate in javascript this data to do something like that this.$title.html(datos);  with ajax I return the view and now I try to return this value

Comment: So far, this looks ok.  Can you add `console.log(datos)` before the `datos = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` line, and show what it prints in the console (usually Ctrl+Shift+J)?

Comment: Thanks again @RocketHazmat the consola show me this Array[2]
0: Object
1: Object  inside 0 and 1 there are my values... but why repeat the value? and now How I obtain the value? I write alert(datos[0]) and show me object object

Comment: Your object was automatically parsed by jQuery, so you can remove the `datos = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` line.  Also, your object is actually an Array of multiple Objects!  Try `alert(data[0].name)`.

Comment: thank @RocketHazmat but I can´t take out the value outside the function. If outside of function "devuelve" I do a alert(datos[0].name) return indefinide and the console return null. Why? I new the value outside of there to do this this.$description.html(datos.name);

Comment: It's because it's asynchronous.  You can read the value until it's downloaded.  You need to do all your work inside the callback.  `devuelve (eldata.link, function(response){ alert(response[0].name); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
alert(datos.nombre)
```

Hope this helps

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: This is the same as `datos["nombre"]`, which he claims doesn't work.